# Adding objects from one list to another

Tags: c#, list

I'm having two lists were one of the lists `InboxTemp` is automatically is filled with all the objects that exists. The other list `NewMessages` is randomly (10-60sec) recieving new objects. The problem I have is that I want `allList` to add the objects in `newList` without any duplicates.

```
public List<object> GetNewMessages()
{
    if (NewMessages.Count > 0 && InboxTemp.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NewMessages.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < InboxTemp.Count; i++)
            {
                if (InboxTemp[i].ID != NewMessages[j].ID)
                {
                    InboxTemp.Add(NewMessages[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    NewMessages.Clear();
    return InboxTemp;
}
```

The problem here is that we get duplicates, I just want the new objects to addup with the `InboxTemp`-list .

Comment: have a look at the except method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb908822(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Also, have you tried `List<T>.Contains()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var newItems = NewMessages.Where(x => !InboxTemp.Any(z => z.ID == x.ID));
InboxTemp.AddRange(newItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, please create class implementing IEqualityComparer to compare objects id.

```
class MyEqualityComparerer : IEqualityComparer<MyMessage>
    {
        public bool Equals(MyMessage x, MyMessage y)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (x == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (y == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return x.Id == y.Id;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(MyMessage obj)
        {
            if(obj == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Then write get Distinct values from messages and add all not present in the old list to it

```
var newItems = newList.Distinct(new MyEqualityComparerer()).Except(oldList, new MyEqualityComparerer()).ToList();
        oldList.AddRange(newItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use except:

```
InboxTemp = InboxTemp.Except(NewMessages);
```

From MSDN:

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values....
>
> ...The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of
>   the types that implement the IEqualityComparer(Of T) generic
>   interface. To compare a custom data type, **you need to implement this
>   interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the
>   type.**

Source: [MSDN Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

Comment: Works not without a custom IEqualityComparer<T> since it's a custom class which would compare just for reference-equality by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.Except` to find all new messages.

```
public List<Msg> GetNewMessages()
{
    var newMsg = NewMessages.Except(InboxTemp, new MsgComparer()).ToList();
    foreach(var msg in newMsg)
        InboxTemp.Add(msg);
    return newMsg;
}
```

But you need to create a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your object (i'll call it `Msg`):

```
public class MsgComparer: IEqualityComparer<Msg>
{
    public bool Equals(Msg x1, Msg x2)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x1, x2))
            return true;
        if (x1 == null || x2 == null)
            return false;
        return x1.ID.Equals(x2.ID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Msg obj)
    {
        return obj.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modified code based on what you posted:

```
public List<object> GetNewMessages()
        {
            if (NewMessages.Count > 0 && InboxTemp.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < NewMessages.Count; j++)
                {
                    bool found = false;
                    int i = 0;
                    while(!found && i<InboxTemp.Count)
                    {
                        if (InboxTemp[i].ID == NewMessages[j].ID)
                        {
                            found = true;
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                    if(!found)
                        InboxTemp.Add(NewMessages[j]);
                }
            }
            NewMessages.Clear();
            return InboxTemp;
        }
```